# How to resolve when getting Red 'X' mark on the icon in project,

Tags: eclipse

I have a Java Maven project where it has Red 'X' mark on the icon in project(s).

However, I can not see error on the packages, class etc.
I checked project > properties and the library list and there is no
error there either.

How do I find out what error the project is hitting?

Comment: There is a "Problems" view in eclipse if I remember correctly.

Comment: Yes, getting problems in eclips

Comment: Goto: "Window" > "Show View" > "Problems"